# How to stop FFImageLoading gif loop?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, ffimageloading

I've loaded a GIF using `FFImageLoading`, but that GIF is keep looping again and again. Is there a way to stop that loop?

```
<ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage x:Name="Logo" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="resource://Images.srw-logo-animation.gif"/>
```

In here `Logo` is the x Referece of that tag.

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Christian Baumann Well, that is one line SvgCachedImage tag, so I thought won't be necessary. I've updated the code. Please check

Comment: It is an open feature request: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/859 Number of repeats to GIF image - #718